# MatrixPower in 11.0.1

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, implementation-details

For a square matrix $M$, consider $M^8$.

Does `MatrixPower[M, 8]` do seven matrix multiplications?  Or is it smart enough to compute $((M^2)^2)^2$ that involves only three?

Or does *Mathematica* do something else?

Comment: The "Details" section of the [documentation for `MatrixPower`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixPower.html) states that "`MatrixPower[m, n]` effectively evaluates the product of a matrix with itself $n$ times."

Comment: @MarcoB I think a key word there is "effectively".  It should give the same result, but I doubt that it does that since it wouldn't be the most efficient.  I don't know what it does, but what makes sense to me is to switch methods based on whether the matrix is symbolic, exact numeric, inexact numeric or machine precision numeric, as well as based on the matrix size and the exponent.

Comment: If you only want to know which method is faster, just benchmark it.

Comment: This is just a guess, but for machine precision matrices a major concern could be numerical stability and hence a different method might be needed to ensure the answer is even *correct*. Now whether the 'nested power' method is as numerically stable as say diagonalization, I'm not sure...

Answer (score 6):

Benchmark:

```
M = RandomReal[10, {10, 10}];
RepeatedTiming[M.M.M.M.M.M.M.M;, 10]
RepeatedTiming[MatrixPower[M, 8];, 10]
RepeatedTiming[temp = M.M;
 temp = temp.temp;
 temp.temp;, 10]
```

> `{7.7*10^-6, Null}`
>
> `{3.1*10^-6, Null}`
>
> `{3.60*10^-6, Null}`

So it appears some optimization does take place, as the timing is much closer to the $((M^2)^2)^2$ method.

Comment: Repeat Feyre's benchmark with `M = Array[x, {5, 5}];` and there's an even more dramatic difference.

Comment: Especially for high powers I could imagine it might be faster to diagonalize first if that's possible

Comment: @JulesLamers The exact case e.g. integer or rational input would be ill suited for diagonalizing since that involves working in an algebraic extension field. For the inexact case this might make sense. For real input there will be fuzzy nonzero imaginary parts and offhand I don't know if they should be left alone or chopped off (probably the latter is my guess).

Comment: @Jules, in addition to Daniel's comments, recall that not all matrices are diagonalizable; one can ostensibly use Schur before powering in the inexact case, tho. In the exact and symbolic cases, one could use Jordan, but then you hit the problem alluded in Daniel's first sentence.

Comment: @J.M. Certainly, hence the "if that's possible" :)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Thanks for the comment!